# Force child to call parent method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have this situation:

```
abstract class A implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.abstractMethod();
    }

    abstract abstractMethod();
}

class B extends A implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        doOtherStuff();
    }
      
    abstractMethod() {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

My problem is that B is not forced to call super.ngOnInit() inside it's ngOnInit method so abstractMethod is not called. Is there a way to force B to call super.ngOnInit()?

I'm asking this because I'm trying to create a base component for standard actions but some child components needs to do other things in ngOnInit (plus call abstractMethod()) and I'm trying to avoid mistakes caused by forgetfulness.

Comment: But you are not calling `super.ngOnInit()`... why?

Comment: What I want is the compiler to force me to call super.ngOnInit(). I don't want to be forced to remember that.

Comment: Can you add the call to the constructor? That must be called.

Comment: But you are overloading ngOnInit, it would be kind of weird if the compiler would call the base one for you, because it would be against overloading.

Comment: you're mixing concepts. One Component can `implements` another component (In Class is called a Class children of another one). Other thing is a Component that can be "parent" of another when **inside** the .html of the parent is the "tag" with the child

Comment: But what I'm trying to achieve is a partial implementation. I mean: many of my components needs to subscribe to the same subject and unsubscribe during onDestroy hook and I want to avoid code replication as well as forgetfulness errors (super not called).
I can move the subscribe action from ngOnInit to constructor and solve the "issue" but I cannot do the same for the unsubscribe which needs to be placed in the ngOnDestroy method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem.
you can use this approach:

```js
abstract class A implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.abstractMethod();
        this.childOnInit();
    }

    abstract abstractMethod();
    abstract childOnInit();
}

class B extends A {
    childOnInit() {
        doOtherStuff();
    }
      
    abstractMethod() {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```